# turn off asmtools class file version check

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

So I have a classes containing bytecode I need to debug ...

Using [asmtools](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/asmtools)' `jdis` gives me editable bytecode that I then can reassemble using `jasm`.

Or at least I can MOST of the time.

For this particular class, though, I can disassemble it just fine. If I do nothing to the file and instead immediately try to reassemble it, `jasm` will claim

> Error: class file version expected

on 69 occasions, most of which seem to be at a `local_map` or `invokestatic` instruction, though there are also a few at `istore` or `iconst_1` instructions.

I'd say that's an unnecessary check gone haywire. After all, I do have a `.class` file that runs just fine (except that it's giving me a `ClassCastException` where there shouldn't be one, but that won't corrupt bytecode).

Can I somehow turn that off?

Comment: This looks like a parser error, as the message doesn’t indicate that it is actually checking a class file version but *expecting* the declaration of a version. For simple parsers, this often indicates that whatever it has found was unexpected, but generating useful error messages just given the rule set and input, is a different science. Sometimes, it’s just a single brace missing or too much, to confuse a parser.

Comment: Have you tried using Krakatau? It has much better error messages. (As well as not having this bug in the first place)